# If/then in google script based on wordings | Add-on in menu bar

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to change a cell (say, B1) into "Correct" if I entered "Apple" in a cell (say, A1). While if I wrote other things, it will still return "Correct", even the cell if not entered in "Apple". May I know how can I fix it?

And what if I allow multiple answers, for instance, if I entered "Apple", "Banana" or "Orange", I can still get "Correct" in cell B1.

```
function myFunction() {

  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var activeSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var workingcell = activeSheet.getRange(1,1).getValue();

  if(workingcell = "Apple"){
    activeSheet.getRange(2,2).setValue("Correct");
    } else {
      activeSheet.getRange(2,2).setValue("Wrong");
  }
}
```

I would also like to customize the menu bar in the google sheet, which others can simply click the button to run the code. While seems like it is not working, how can I fix it?

```
function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var entries = [{
    name : "Run",
    functionName : "Run"
  }
                ];
  sheet.addMenu("Run", entries);
};
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) and [mcve]. [Google Apps Script Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script)

Comment: Question posts on this site should include only one question.

Answer (score 3):

On the following line

```
if(workingcell = "Apple"){
```

change `=` by `===`

The above because in JavaScript/Google Apps Script a single equal sign is used to assign a value/object to a variable. The two and three equal signs are used to do equality comparisons, abstract and strict respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var entries = [];
  entries.push({name : "MenuItem1",functionName : "function1"});
  entries.push({name : "MenuItem2",functionName : "function2"});
  sheet.addMenu("My Menu", entries);
};

function function1() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast('function1');
}

function function2() {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast('function2');
}
```